# How to manage WebFormViews on an ASP.NET Web Application?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms

I have an ASP.NET Web Application on .NET Framework 4.5.1 where I have defined several controllers, functions, and also a WebForm. The current default page when loading the app is the "asp.net" help page, on the HomeController the Index method is looking like this:

```
 public ViewResult Index()
    { 
        ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";

        return View();
    }
```

It seems that the default view type is .cshtml pages, but I cannot code in javascript so I had to use a WebForm (.aspx.cs) as my CodeBehind is all in C#. What do I need to do the change the default / initial view to my .aspx page that I have created? "HomePage.aspx"

Comment: You created an MVC project. If you wanted a Web Forms site, why didn't you select that option when creating the project? And in 2020, why are you wanting to create a new Web Forms site to begin with?

Comment: Hi mason, basically as i had no idea what the appropriate project type was when i started (i still don't know the difference), i only have prior experience in windows form apps / c# so this is entirely new to me. I only need a 'Web' Interface for end users to interact with API functionality that i have developed (i am currently using PostMan) - can you please advise the best '2020' approach to this would be?

Comment: Avoid Web Forms at all costs. That's rule #1. As far as what to do instead, that's a lot more flexible and depends on the needs of the project and what the team is comfortable with. ASP.NET Core MVC or ASP.NET Core Razor are decent choices, as is a SPA application with a JS front end such as React, Angular, or Vue combined with ASP.NET Core MVC as a Web API. You need to research your options. I can't really dictate to you what the best is, other than saying that Web Forms is hard to work with, slow, hard to update, and basically unsupported.